# Linking CXX executable xxx :undefined reference to `stlp_std::cout'

Tags: makefile, cmake, stlport

I was trying to convert an existed `c++` project to `CMake`. The existed worked well with makefile, and i have converted similar one successfully.  but when i try to convert this one, some confusing errors occurred, as below：

```
18:22:10: Running steps for project encryption... 
18:22:10: Starting: "/export/opt/cmake-3.2.2/bin/cmake" --build . --target all 
Linking CXX executable dist/Debug_64/GNU-Linux-x86/encryption 
CMakeFiles/encryption.dir/encryption.cc.o: In function `main': 
/export1/chao/nanos/nano_clean/nano_clean/src/encryption/encryption.cc:33: undefined reference to `stlp_std::cout' 
...
/export1/chao/nanos/nano_clean/nano_clean/lib/STLport/stlport/stl/_string.c:604: undefined reference to `stlp_std::__stl_throw_out_of_range(char const*)' 
...
```

At first i think it can't find `iostream`, so i include `iostream` at /`export1/chao/nanos/nano_clean/nano_clean/lib/STLport/stlport/ by using 'INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES'`, but it did not work. Could you please give me some advices? 
My CMakeLists.txt as below:

```
include_directories(/export1/chao/nanos/nano_clean/nano_clean/lib/STLport/stlport)
include_directories(/export1/chao/nanos/nano_clean/nano_clean/lib/STLport/stlport/h/using)
include_directories(/export1/chao/nanos/nano_clean/nano_clean/lib/boost/1.49.0/boost/tr1/tr1)
link_directories(
../common/dist/${CONF}/GNU-Linux-x86
/export2/chao/nanos/nano_built/lib/tiburonda/dist/include
)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
include_directories(../common/include
)
add_executable(encryption ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(encryption libcommon.a)
```

According to `original makefile`, i found this project use `source file` `encryption.cc` at `./`, `header files`: `encryption.h` at `./` and others at `../common/include`.

Comment: Error `undefined reference` usually signals about missed call to `target_include_libraries`. If you need need more concrete help, provide [mcve].

Comment: It appears that you need to link the stlport library and aren't doing so.
Of course, can't see your error without seeing your `CMakeLists`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks, you point the key for me, i would try to link std lib immediately.

Comment: @MikeKinghan, thanks a lot, i have re-edit my question, and the CMakeLists.txt is at the bottom, thanks a lot if you can help me find any wrong.

Comment: The first step to get what _actually_ is going wrong with CMake-based build is to use `make VERBOSE=1`. It turns off all fancy output and displays actual compiler/linker commands being executed.